# Blackberry BrowserField white empty page issue

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

Hi i want to show html content in BrowserField. I used the code blove to do this but i only see white empty page.

```
BrowserField demo = new BrowserField(); 
String res="<html><body><p>demo</p></body></html>"; 

demo.displayContent(res, "http://localhost");
```

Sometimes it shows my page correctly with css fonts but sometimes it does not show anything.

What is the problem in my code?

Comment: You did remember to call `add(demo);` in the parent `Manager`, yes?

Comment: Yes `add(demo);` called but the order was wrong. `add(demo);` then `demo.displayContent(...);` solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look [at this BlackBerry example](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Display_HTML_in_a_browser_field_825639_11.jsp),

they make sure to `add()` the `BrowserField` to its parent `Manager` **before** calling `displayContent()`.

I don't know if you just omitted that line of code to shorten your question, if you're missing the call to `add()` entirely, or if you put it **after** the call to `displayContent()`.  But, try doing it in the order listed in the BlackBerry example, and let me know if that works.

```java
BrowserField demo = new BrowserField(); 
add(demo);
String res="<html><body><p>demo</p></body></html>"; 
demo.displayContent(res, "http://localhost");
```

Comment: i checked my code and i saw that `add(demo)` called after `displayContent();` now problem is solved. Thanks